# Как отфильтровать по подстроке записи модели?

Tags: python, django

Я делаю поисковик по модели `vedModel`. Мне требуется, чтобы при вводе подстроки, например `уче`, я получал все варианты записей из модели `vedModel` с заголовком (полем `topic`), то есть, например, `учебник и тетрадь, за партами ученики, школьные принадлежности - это и учебники` и т.д.

модель vedModel

```
class vedModel(models.Model):

    topic = models.CharField('Тема', max_length = 100, null = True, )

    # категория, подкатегория
    category = models.CharField('Категория', max_length = 40, null = True, blank = True, )
    sub_category = models.CharField('Подкатегория', max_length = 40, null = True, blank = True, )
```

виев

```
from django.http import JsonResponse#, HttpResponse

# статьи
from ved.models.article import vedModel




# вернт рекламные баннеры
def ajax_searchDef(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':

        # текст поискового запроса
        search = request.GET['search']

        res_list = []

        # тут должна быть фильтрация по подстроке
        

        return JsonResponse({'res_list': res_list, })
```

Answer (score 0):

[Ответ здесь можно посмотреть (доки django(надо написать мин.30 символов)))](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#contains)